# 64-Bit Java won't use >2GB RAM

Tags: java, minecraft, heap-size

I'm having some issues running minecraft on my PC (specifically, some demanding mods). MC issues aside- I'm noticing that Minecraft/Java Platform does not want to use more than about 2,900 MB of memory. My PC has 32GB RAM to work with so I'd be happy, for example, doubling or quadrupling this number.

Most resources suggest changing the environment settings with the -Xmx[MEM] tag. I have tried this, restarted PC, to non avail- the memory does not budge past ~2,900MB.

[image]

I've also double-checked the Java version- I'm running the latest 64-Bit build so I don't think I'm encountering the common issue of 32-Bit systems not allowing >2GB heap size.

[image]

Can anyone help me out here? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something? Tysm!

Comment: Is the program compiled as 64 bit? Else it wont help much to install a different runtime.

Comment: Ok I found a resource on this but there isn't a clear answer AFAICT: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/any-benefits-to-running-minecraft-in-a-64bit-environment

Comment: Bytecode is word-size agnostic. How do you know memory is maxed out? OOM error? Maybe it doesn't need more than 2900MB?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `-d64` is largely ignored / deprecated at this point. Additionally MC doesn't load the entirety of worlds at a time, 2.5gb with no players on it is more than reasonable. `-Xmx` represents the ceiling, not an initial allocation (that'd be `-Xms`). Overall though, you can largely run minecraft with just `-Xmx` and it'll expand if it needs to.

Comment: To answer both  questions, the limitations of 2GB RAM aren't apparent on either multiplayer or standard vanilla gameplay. I'm noticing them in two scenarios- (1) using Carpet mod to warp the game ticks as fast as possible, which basically stress tests the machine's capability and hits a max of 1800 TPS/2900MB memory, (2) performance issues with replay mod rendering/editing (again maxing out the memory and causing crashes due to insufficient heap size). The purpose here isn't to debug these issues on the level of the individual mods but to ask, can I have more RAM at all? @Rogue

Comment: 1800 TPS is counter-productive, you're just going to throttle the server doing that (That's an attempted tick every `0.55` milliseconds!). If you actually get an out of memory error, post it here (and we'll likely be able to see to what extent it was breaking).

Comment: @Rogue I'm playing in singleplayer, not a server. To reiterate the purpose here isn't to debug these issues on the level of the individual mods but to ask, can I have more RAM at all?

Comment: If you start Java with -Xmx8g then it will allocate up to 8gb for the heap - if your application ever needs that amount of memory. Note that there are besides an exhausted heap other causes for `OutOfMemoryError` (for example if Java tries to start a new Thread but no native threads are available). It would be helpful if you could share more information about the error that you get (for example an exception log with stack trace)